# how to reroute old html pages?

Tags: plugin-development, routes

I want to reroute old html pages.
The format is:  /title-35-of-page.863.en.html
I want to route every adresse with .html at the end also get the lang and id part of the address for further handling, but have problems with the dots.
This are some versions that i tried, but none of them worked.

```
'(?P<title>[-\w\d]+).html' => array('action' => 'jpk/rerouteOldPages')
'(?P<title>[-\w\d]+)html' => array('action' => 'jpk/rerouteOldPages')
'(?P<title>[-\w\d]+)\.(?P<papayaId>\d+)\.(?P<language>\[a-z]{2})\.html' => array('action' => 'jpk/rerouteOldPages')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this works, the backslash behind "...language>" was wrong:

```
'(?P<title>[-\w\d]+)\.(?P<papayaId>\d+)\.(?P<language>[\w]{2})\.html' => array('action' => 'jpk/rerouteOldPages'),
```